# Append files to an existing zip file with Poco::Zip

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

After successfully compress the folder, here is my situation :

If `append = true` and `overWrite = false` I have to check whether if the target zip file exists or not if existed I will check the existed zip file which files it doesn't contain and append new file from the source folder to it.

My question is:

- How can I open the zip file and put it to the compress object? or which others library in Poco should I use to open zip stream? I'm trying to use `std::ifstream` but Poco::zip::Compress doesn't seem to receive an `std::ifstream`

I surely have to modify the Poco source code itself to match with my requirement. Thanks in advance.

```
 void ZipFile(string source, string target, List extensions, bool append, bool overWrite)
    {    
        Poco::File tempFile(source);
        if (tempFile.exists())
        {
            if (Poco::File(target).exists() && append && !overWrite) {

            fs::path targetPath = fs::path(target);
            std::ifstream targetFileStream(targetPath.string(), std::ios::binary);

            std::ofstream outStream(target, ios::binary);
            CompressEx compress(outStream, false, false);

            if (tempFile.isDirectory())
            {
                Poco::Path sourceDir(source);
                sourceDir.makeDirectory();
                compress.addRecursive(sourceDir, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                    Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_NORMAL, false);
            }
            else if (tempFile.isFile())
            {
                Poco::Path path(tempFile.path());
                compress.addFile(path, path.getFileName(), Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                    Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_NORMAL);
            }

            compress.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
            outStream.close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to modify the Poco source code. Poco allows you to [get the contents of an archive](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.ZipArchive.html) and [add files to it](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.ZipManipulator.html).

First, open the target archive to check which files are already in there:

```
Poco::ZipArchive archive(targetFileStream);
```

Then collect all files you want to add, that are not in the archive, yet:

```
std::vector<fs::path> files;
if (fs::is_directory(source)) {
    for(auto &entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator())
        // if entry is file and not in zip
        if (fs::is_regular_file(entry)
            && archive.findHeader(fs::relative(entry.path, source)) == archive.headerEnd()) {
            files.push_back(entry.path);
        }
} else if (fs::is_regular_file(entry)
           && archive.findHeader(source) == archive.headerEnd()) {
    files.push_back(source);
}
```

Finally, add the files to your zip

```
Poco::Zip::ZipManipulator manipulator(target, false);
for(auto &file : files)
    manipulator.addFile(fs::relative(file, source), file,
                        Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                        Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_NORMAL);
```

I had no opportunity to test this. So try it out and see what needs to be done to make it work.

Comment: Tks for your help, I will try it.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm Btw. if you want to use the same solution when `overWrite` is true, you can use `ZipManipulator::replace`.

Comment: `fs::relative(file, source)` there is something wrong with this line, I'm using C++14.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm Nobody is able to help you without ab error message. You'll have to fix it yourself.

Comment: namespace "std::experimental::filesystem" has no member "relative". Here is the error message.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm Yeah, `fs::relative` was not part of the experimental Filesystem TS and is C++17 and above only. If you choose not to remove `source` from the path, your zip will look like this `zip:/source/foo/bar` instead of this `zip:/foo/bar`. If that is not a problem, just omit `fs::relative`. If it is, remove the first directory of the `file` path using classic string operations like [`string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [`string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm For the manual string modification, you may want to get the absolute path of `source` and `file` first using `fs::canonical` and then remove the common prefix from `file`.

Comment: I have successfully detected the new files, but still not able to append it into the zip file.

Comment: `manipulator.addFile` after addFile. Should we use another member function with Poco::Zip::Manipulator which is `commit()` to re-create the zip file with changes? I facing the error here.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm Yes. Why didn' you just try it out?

Comment: I have tried several other classes `Poco::Zip::Add` and your example but still not work. Poco is an open-source of C++ that I don't see many examples for you to study, so I got stuck. Thanks a lot, mate, I will try it myself.

Comment: Have you looked here https://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html